# How to modify Pandas DataFrame based on reversed Dictionary values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Context:**

I have a dictionary and a Dataframe.

```
categories = { "Transport": ["taxi", "b u s", "bike"],
               "Housing": ["r-ent","jysk", "ikea"]}

data = { "Date": ["2020-09-29", "2020-09-29", "2020-09-29"],
         "Amount": [-28.0, -20.0 , -13.7],
         "Title": ["ny taxi", "brooklyn*ikea", "Burger Joint Co"],
         "Category": [None, None, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", "Amount", "Title", "Category"])
```

**Problem:**

For each row of the Dataframe, I need to check if the value in the Dataframe["Title"] column contains one of the values in the dictionary list. If the list item is found in the value then the Dataframe["Category"] column should take the Key of the list where the match was found.

For example, "taxi" is a keyword in the dictionary list under the key "Transportation". Therefore the row that has "ny taxi" should have "Transportation" in the Category column.

**Starting Dataframe:**

```
     Date  Amount            Title     Category
0  2020-09-29   -28.0          ny taxi     None
1  2020-09-29   -20.0    brooklyn*ikea     None
2  2020-09-29   -13.7  Burger Joint Co     None
```

**Desired Output:**

```
         Date  Amount            Title   Category
0  2020-09-29   -28.0          ny taxi  Transport
1  2020-09-29   -20.0    brooklyn*ikea    Housing
2  2020-09-29   -13.7  Burger Joint Co    Missing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is loop by dictionary and test joined values by `|` for regex `or` by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and set values by mask in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
for k, v in categories.items():
    df.loc[df['Title'].str.contains('|'.join(v)), 'Category'] = k
 
df['Category'] = df['Category'].fillna('Missing')
 
print (df)
         Date  Amount            Title   Category
0  2020-09-29   -28.0          ny taxi  Transport
1  2020-09-29   -20.0    brooklyn*ikea    Housing
2  2020-09-29   -13.7  Burger Joint Co    Missing
```

Or you can join all values of dictionary, use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first matched value and then mapping dictionary with changed keys with values in [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(x for k, v in categories.items() for x in v))
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in categories.items() for k in oldv}
df['Category'] =  df['Title'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).map(d).fillna('Missing')
print (df)
         Date  Amount            Title   Category
0  2020-09-29   -28.0          ny taxi  Transport
1  2020-09-29   -20.0    brooklyn*ikea    Housing
2  2020-09-29   -13.7  Burger Joint Co    Missing
```

Comment: Thank you! the first solution worked beautifully! 
Is there a performance advantage when using first or second versions?

Comment: @Geom - I think it depends of data, how many values in dictioanry, how long lists in each key in dictionary, what is number of rows in DataFrame. So the best test both.